# How to execute custom query in CakePHP

Tags: php, sql, cakephp

I'm currently trying to execute custom queries in CakePHP framework, meaning instead of using CakePHP syntax, I'd like execute normal SQL query like `SELECT * FROM post ORDER BY id desc`.

I cannot figure out how to do it. I read several answers to the similar questions, but it still doesn't work.

As far as I understand I should put function like:

```
public function testx()
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WORDER by id desc";
    return $this->query($sql);
}
```

to file `Post` in directory `Model` and then put this code:

```
$result = $this->Post->testx();
```

to `index` function in `PostsController` in `Controller` directory.

I still can't figure out how to print out the data in `View/Posts/index.ctp`.

Thanks in advance for any answer.

Comment: Why would you execute the most trivial SQL queries as plain SQL while the ORM provides a ton of features and proper escaping? Even very complex queries can be build using the ORM. What you do is IMHO just wrong and negates the benefits of a framework.

Answer (score 11):

```
public function index(){
    $this->loadModel('Post'); //or you can load it in beforeFilter()
    $data=$this->Post->query('SELECT * FROM posts ORDER by id desc');
    $this->set('data',$data);
}
```

In your view file **index.ctp**. Write Below Code

```
<?php
     if($data) {
          echo "<pre>";
          print_r($data);
     } else {
          echo 'no data found';
     }
?>
```

Comment: What about queries with parameters?

Comment: @ZiadAkiki Could you please elaborate on it? So, I can help.

Comment: does `$this->Post->query('SELECT * FROM posts ORDER by id desc WHERE id = ?', $id);` for example works? In other words, if I need to pass a parameter in the query securely.

Comment: @ZiadAkiki Yes. You can pass the parameters. I believe you should go with CakePHP 3 ORM rather than a Query Builder to secure the query. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

> If you want to execute a delete (or any other) query without a model then you should try

```
$db = ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default');
$db->rawQuery("DELETE FROM table WHERE id=5");
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use connection manager to run custom SQL queries. Follow this article from cake php documentation to use connection manager: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html

```
use Cake\Datasource\ConnectionManager;
$connection = ConnectionManager::get('default');
$results = $connection->execute('SELECT * FROM articles')->fetchAll('assoc');
```

After this to view results in your view (index.ctp) you have to set the result variable

```
$this->set('result',$result);
```

Now you can view the data from your database in index.ctp using the result variable.

Answer (score 2):

```
App::import("Model", "ModelName");  
    $model = new ModelName();  
    $query = "Select * from tablename";
    $data = $model->query($query);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$this->Post->query("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER by id desc");
```

Answer (score 0):

Controller

```
$result = $this->Post->testx();
$this->set('posts', $result);
```

View

```
debug($posts);
foreach ($posts as $post) {
   // ...
}
```

Comment: I tried that but instead off printing out the variable I get "Notice (8): Undefined index: Post [APP/View/Posts/index.ctp, line 17]". I use $post['Post']['id'] to print out the variable. But it prints out that same error message for all the rows in the table, so the SQL query is at least partly working.

Comment: did you use `debug($posts)` ? It might be $post['post'].

Answer (score 0):

No need to make such extra **function testx()** in this case. You can also use the custom query directly in your index function like,

```
public function index(){
    $data=$this->Post->query('SELECT * FROM posts ORDER by id desc');
    $this->set('data',$data);
}
```

and in your **index.ctp file** just print the data,

```
<?php print_r($data); ?>
```

Hope this will help you.