# CakePHP - insert into multiple tables error

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm trying to save data to more tables using CakePHP (2.4.6).

I have Posts/add.tcp file:

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('Post');
echo $this->Form->input('title');
echo $this->Form->input('body', array('rows' => '3'));
echo $this->Form->end('Save Post');
?>
```

And method add in PostsController file:

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->request->data['Post']['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');

$titulek = $this->request->data['Post']['title'];
$uid=$this->request->data['Post']['user_id'];
$body=$this->request->data['Post']['body'];

$sqla = "INSERT INTO posts (title,created,user_id) VALUES ('$titulek', NOW(),'$uid')";
$sqlb = "INSERT INTO forums (user_id,post_id,text,created) VALUES ('$uid',NULL,'$body', NOW())";

if ($this->Post->query($sqla)) {
if ($this->Post->query($sqlb)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your post has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
}
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work as intended. Only `$sqla` query is actually saved to the database. `$sqlb` query isn't executed at all and at the end I'm not redirected to another page. It's interesting that if I reverse the order of queries (e.g. current `$sqlb` query becomes `$sqla` query and `$sqlb` query becomes `$sqla` query the `INSERT INTO forums` query executes correctly but `INSERT INTO posts` isn't, so it seems that both queries are written correctly and for some reason only first of them executes). What am I doing wrong? I just want to insert custom query into more tables in one action. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: is there any particular reason you're using `query` instead of `save()` function?

Comment: Yes, it's easier to directly execute the query I need to execute rather then using complicated CakePHP syntax. (I'm doing this mainly as a school project and I have to use PHP framework even though it just makes things more complicated for me.)

Comment: Are you receiving any error messages? What happens if you try to put in dummy data for one of the variables such as the `$body`? Any chance that you need to escape the data in `$body`? What happens when you try `var_dump($this->Post->query($sqlb));`?

Comment: That's a nice SQL injection vulnerability you have there :) [**You have been warned**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22745570/how-to-execute-custom-query-in-cakephp#comment34680457_22745570), that's what you get for not using this oh so complicated CakePHP syntax...

Comment: @bigmike7801 : **var_dump($this->Post->query($sqlb));** added to PostController.php add function function prints array(0) { } regardless of the input data. Interestingly if I put var_dump function there it inserts data correctly into both tables, but it doesn't redirect. And yes, I am aware that currently there's SQL injection vulnerability and I'll fix it after it's working properly (e.g. inserting in both table and redirecting as it should).

Comment: What if you used mysqli_real_escape_string($body) instead of just $body?

Comment: @bigmike7801 : I tried that but it gives me an error **Warning (2): mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given [APP/Controller/PostsController.php, line 46]** and I'm not sure what am I supposed to put as the other parameter. If I try mysql instead mysqli, it gives me an error too. But I don't think that has anything to do with what I'm asking. I tried to replace variables in $sqla and $sqlb with specific text and numbers (e.g. instead of '$body', I put 'text') but it works same way as with variables. $sqla gets executed and $sqlb doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

So let me clear this up, besides the obvious SQL injection problem that you have there (when executing raw queries, always use [**prepared statements**](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#prepared-statements) so that the data is being bound in a safe way), you are not evaluating the return value of [**`Model::query()`**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#model-query) properly.

### Evaluating Model::query() results

Unfortunately the documentation is a little misleading/confusing/incorrect on this, an `INSERT` query will always return an empty array on success, so you would have to check for something like:

```
is_array($this->Post->query($sqla))
```

However that's pretty ugly if you ask me.

### DboSource::execute() for INSERTs

For an `INSERT` query I'd always use [**`DboSource::execute()`**](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-DboSource.html#_execute), which also supports binding parameters:

```
$db = ConnectionManager::getDataSource('default');
$options = array();
$params = array(
    ':title' => $titulek,
    ':uid' => $uid,
);
$result = $db->execute(
    'INSERT INTO posts (title,created,user_id) VALUES (:title, NOW(), :uid)',
    $options,
    $params
);
```

Now `$result` will bei either an instance of [**`PDOStatement`**](http://php.net/manual/class.pdostatement.php) on success, or `false` on failure, so it would be safe to simply test the value for being truly:

```
if($result)
```

### CakePHP ORM to the rescue

If you use a framework, *use* the framework!

As already mentioned in the comments, if possible you should avoid executing queries manually, the ORM layer offers great comfort and security, and is as simple to use as:

```
$this->Post->save($this->request->data)
```

All you have to do is set up your model associations, and make sure that the view formats the data properly.

However, your DB schema seems pretty weird, I really don't get why you create a forum for every post, where the forum contains the post contents, lacking any association to the post o_O Maybe you should rethink that.

Further information:

- **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html**
- **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html**

Answer (score 1):

### You are making life hard for yourself

> [This is for] a school project and I have to use PHP framework

If you're going to use a PHP framework - you should *use* it and not just shoehorn plain php code into your controllers. If using a framework is part of the task it's not going to go in your favor that your code is *not* using the framework as designed; apart from not using the ORM - controller code should never contain sql, which is an indicator of not using models appropriately (or at all).

The equivalent controller code you need is no more than:

```
public function add() {
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->request->data['Post']['user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');
        if ($this->Post->saveAssociated($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Your post has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
    }
}
```

This code show above will (in contrast to the code in the question):

- Validate your user input
- Show error messages next to inputs if appropriate (e.g. "body cannot be empty")
- Protect you from sql injection (as it uses parameterized sql statements)
- Actually work as expected

It is not apparent how the Post and Forum models are related (the post model is used in the form, but data is inserted into different tables, and what looks like the post-body is inserted into the forums table - that's confusing), calling [saveAssociated](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html#model-saveassociated-array-data-null-array-options-array) (or saveAll) with appropriate request data will insert into both posts and forums with the desired data.

Note that this code is [very similar to the blog tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/blog.html) - which normally takes about 15 minutes for new developers to run through.